# Simple .htaccess password generation / update using PHP without database

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2, password-protection

I am using Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0. I have `.htaccess` file in one of my directories. I want to password protect it with multiple usernames and passwords.

How can I create usernames and passwords and update it using PHP, by my own, without using a database service such as MySQL, and using some text file to store login information, so that I can have my own signup or add/update user page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could run apache's `htpasswd` on the command line via `system()` or `exec()`. This way you're sure that you are using the correct password generation method.
2. Do it yourself in pure php with `file()` and `explode` and use `crypt` to hash the passwords.

Comment: can you suggest me a tutorial?? i am a beginner.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write in your password file using PHP. The passwords can be encrypted using MD5 so no problem with PHP.

Comment: can you suggest me a tutorial?? i am a beginner.. :)

Comment: Then start with the beginning: the PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php Btw, I wouldn't use htaccess protection when using PHP unless you want to protect every file in some folder. Sessions would be far more handy.

Comment: I think .htaccess is the best way to protect page since I am looking for a database-less solution. Keeping my protected pages under a directory will prevent my pages and sub dirs from unwanted access.. Am I right?? :)

Comment: Doing it at the PHP level means that only PHP scripts will be protected, unless you're mediating EVERYTHING through PHP. Doing the password prompting via the web server protects EVERYTHING.

Comment: Then you need to parse the password file before blindly adding to it. This is not very handy but doable. You could use a side-file to "emulate" a database: store a serialized version of your logins/passwords and then regenerate the whole password file everytime you add or edit a user.

Answer (score 0):

You phrased your question like you want htpasswd protection, but since you're wanting to add/remove users via a front-end, you'll either have to run system commands via PHP or build a PHP/MySQL solution.

It would probably be easier and safer for you to implement a PHP/MySQL only solution. Running sysetem() and exec() on your computer via PHP is not a very safe thing to do unless you really know what you're doing.

Take a look at this guy's tutorial/php class. It should point you in the correct direction:

http://www.emirplicanic.com/php/simple-php-login-class.php

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a solution without a database service like MySQL. I have reasons :) .... I am trying to depend on .htaccess file or some text file to store login informations

Comment: Then the first two folks will be pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: but I want a beginner tutorial.. It will be fine if U can suggest me one to create and update username and password without using database and store login information in some text file or something else...

Comment: So you plan to develop all your life using tutorials only? Learn the basics, there's enough information here to start digging and writing your own script. Moreover, what you are trying to achieve is not common. htaccess password protection is rarely coupled with PHP adding/editing of users because PHP already provides simplier solutions.